# AWS Fargate tasks takes a while to start when running multiple at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

For some reason, whenever I run multiple ECS tasks too close together, the tasks wont start for a while. If I run at least 7 tasks that are within 5 seconds apart, they will all get stuck in pending without fail. The longest I have waited for it is 20 minutes. Also, when 1 starts, they will all start close to each other. However, if start them far enough from each other, they start fine, usually less than 30 seconds. I run them as Launch Type: Fargate.

Any ideas on why this is happening?